# Get inserted ID or changed rows in sqlite3

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, promise, node-sqlite3

I recently started working with the `sqlite3` package in Node.js. Primarily I'm using the `run`, `all` and `get` functions. Since I like async/await more and those functions are taking callbacks, I used `promisify` from the `util` package to make them use promises that I can await.

```js
import sqlite from 'sqlite3'
import { promisify } from 'util'

const db = new sqlite.Database('./myDatabase.db', (err) => {
    if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected to the database.');
});

db.run = promisify(db.run)
db.all = promisify(db.all)
db.get = promisify(db.get)
```

This works with async/await however a problem shows up when I try to insert or update data using `run()`.

```js
const changedRows = await db.run("UPDATE races SET is_open = false WHERE code = ?", [racecode])
```

When I want to fetch the inserted ID or the affected rows I get `undefined`. That makes sense because the `run` function usually has no argument for a result thus `resolve` yields `undefined`.
From the docs:

```js
db.run(`INSERT INTO langs(name) VALUES(?)`, ['C'], function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err.message);
    }
    // get the last insert id
    console.log(`A row has been inserted with rowid ${this.lastID}`);
  });
```

The question is: Can I even get `this.lastID` from a promisified `run` ? I know there are some wrapper packages for `sqlite3` out there, but I wanna try to use as few packages as possible before adding new ones.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at `better-sqlite3`, which is a full replacement (not a wrapper) and works synchronously. Passing data in `this` sounds like bad design, but if you really want to, you can of course make your own wrapper around `db.run()` using `new Promise()`.

Comment: @robertklep Yeah, that package seems good. I also like the extra performance. The cherry on top would be that I can actually pass true and false in prepared statements for boolean arguments instead of 1 and 0, but I'll get around it. Thanks :)